# Raspberry Pi 3B+ shuts down by itself

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-buster

I’m not well versed enough in Linux to know where to start troubleshooting quite yet, but here’s the situation.

I’ve got a fresh install of Raspbian w/ Desktop on my Raspberry Pi and have it connected through Ethernet to run Pihole and resolve all DNS requests from my router.
Most of the time things are running fine. However, and seemingly at random, I lose network connection on all my devices. The issue? My Pi seems to be turning itself off, or possibly rebooting unsuccessfully.

Only the red power LED is illuminated when I go to investigate the issue, so it doesn’t seem to be doing any reads/writes to the disk while in this “standby” mode. The strangest part is that not only am I able to ping the Pi from my Mac, once I do everything begins to work as intended and internet access is restored to my devices.

Looking through the ‘messages’ log file in /var/log/messages I wasn’t  entirely sure what to look for, or if I was even looking in the right place, but I did notice this string towards the bottom:

```
Dec  2 23:17:06 raspberrypi kernel: [    6.308392] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
```

I have uploaded the entire file [here](https://pastebin.com/aiSKwT2U) in case it would be helpful to anyone trying to assist me in solving this issue. The message I referenced above is located at line 252.

I should also say I’m running the Pi headless and am using the official power supply for my setup.

Comment: Are you using an official Raspberry Pi power supply?

Comment: Yes, I am. I was reading about the possibility of a voltage drop being the cause of my issues, but I’ve been using the same power supply for months without running into this problem.